# I need a query that selects individuals with a birth date from January 1 two years ago through yesterday's date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a query that will pull all children with a birth date from two years ago through yesterday. So using today as a for instance the query would return everyone with BirthDT from 1/1/2018 to 3/4/2020. For the remainder of 2020 the Start Date will always be 1/1/2018 and End Date will vary depending on the date the query is executed. Next year it will need to use 1/1/2019 as the Start Date.

Anything like this of course just give me a rolling two year window. 
`WHERE BirthDT >
   DATEADD(yy, -2, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)))`

Comment: what is the table name ? do you have any sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to create 1.1. of any year and [YEAR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get current year.

For end date, to avoid today's births just cast GETDATE() to DATE

```
WHERE BirthDT >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-2,1,1)
AND BirthDT < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

For datetime fields, it always best to use >= on the left side which will include 0:00 on the starting date, and < on the right side with next day, to get complete data from previous day, if time part is used.

In this case this will include 1.1.2018 0:00:00 and not include 5.3.2020 0:00, but include 4.3.2020 23:59:59

Comment: Genius! Thank you sir.